# Static property - how to properly initialize it?

Tags: c#, static

I'm refactoring some code. I've got many reports in my project which use the same data. For example, each of them uses `List<Product>` which is retrieved via database.

As for now, I have duplicate lines like:

```
var products = MyDatabase.Products.ToList();
```

I'd like to have a static class with static properties that my reports can use.

I want to have a final line in the report something like:

```
var products = MyStaticClass.Products;
```

I'd like to have this list loaded once and enable my reports to use it, instead of referring to the database each time different report wants that list.

I've read about this and the solutions seem to be:

1)

```
public static List<Product> Products 
{
    get
    {
        return MyDatabase.Products.ToList(); 
    }
}
```

2)

```
public static List<Product> Products { get; set;} = MyDatabase.Products.ToList();
```

3)

```
public static List<Product> Products = MyDatabase.Products.ToList();
```

4)

```
private static  List<Product> _products;

public static List<Product> Products
{
    get 
    { 
        return _products ?? 
            ( _products = MyDatabase.Products.ToList()); 
    }
}
```

5.

```
private static Lazy<List<Product>> _products =
    new Lazy<List<Product>>(() => MyDatabase.Products.ToList());

public static List<Product> Products
{
    get { return _products.Value; }
}
```

As I've understood, the first case calls the `MyDatabase.Products.ToList()` each time I access it, so It's not the desired behaviour.

The second option is almost like the first one. Is there any difference? Or just a newer version of the 1st one.

The third option means calling this `MyDatabase.Products.ToList()` only once, but it will always be called, independent of actual usage. Close, I guess.

Are 4th or 5th option superior to those above? Is `Lazy<T>` the best to use in my case? Will it load the data only when called (if called)?

Please clarify if I understand those options correctly and suggest me the perfect solution.

Comment: The First Rule of `static` properties: _don't use_ `static` properties.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit, why? :)

Comment: You could read e.g. [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161222/dont-use-static-in-c/161223).

Comment: The second is not the same as the first.  It will only call the DB when it initializes the property.  You can even remove the `set;` to make it read only.

Comment: @dymanoid The most up-voted answer in your link doesn't really harden your argument.

Comment: You should please read all answers and their comments, but not only the two lines of the mostly upvoted answer. Please also read the answer to your question below.

Comment: @dymanoid Then do tell:  How does making `Math.Add` static hinder testing? Are you really going to swap out implementations of an `Add` method? Does the fact that `Add` itself is static mean that you can't test it? Generally speaking should you avoid `static` methods/properties? In most cases yes. That doesn't mean that `static` is useless in all cases.

Comment: @KennethK., sorry, but `Math.Add` is a method, not a property. Hope you can distinguish them. I was talking about static properties only.

Comment: @dymanoid Then, again, why link to a question that asks about static classes and methods?

Answer (score 2):

This is the worst decision you've ever made: C# is an object-oriented programming, and even in other paradigms, it sounds like a a design smell.

So you want to share some data across many reports: what about dependency injection?  Design your classes so you're able to inject that shared data:

```
public class Report 
{
     public Report(List<Product> products /* other arguments */) 
     {
           Products = products;
     }

     private List<Product> Products { get; }
}
```

### Global state is a bad idea because...

Many can access, modify it. Now add to the equation some threading/parallelism and you'll need extra effort and complexity to synchronize global state's read/write operations.

Also, it's a ticket to memory leaks: those references are alive for the entire application life-cycle.

Avoid global state: embrace dependency injection.

Comment: I swear devs today equate DI to the second coming of Christ. I can just as easily back myself into a similar corner with DI. Given a container that supports it, I can create a single instance of a dependency (i.e singleton) that is reused across all consumers. Is that not itself global state? Personally, I say right tool for the job.

Comment: @Matias Fidelmraizer Thanks for your answer. I'll have to analyse it and see my options. The most experienced developer in my team suggested using statics for this purpose but I think I'll have to talk about this idea.

Comment: @KennethK., yes, that's right. But with a static state, you don't even have any other way than being 'in the corner' of fighting with threading/not-testable/design issues. A DI approach gives you some solutions. You're totally right saying 'right tool', however. DI, as any other tool, should be used appropriately.

Comment: @KennethK. Curiously, I'm far from that background. Anyway, comparing inversion of control to approach singleton pattern with old-school global state in an object-oriented programming language sounds odd.

Comment: @Alice No problem! Discussion sounds like a good way of taking the right decisions :D